# delete method for a queue

Tags: java

I tried to implement a circular queue, where I would like to delete one customer from the queue, however it deletes 2 customers rather than just one. 
An example of this, let's say, I add 4 customers ("Joe", "Mary", "Carol" and "George") in the queue, and they all get displayed. Let's say I want to delete ("Joe") and display the queue. It displays me ("Carol", "George"), meaning that it also deletes "Mary"... I do not know how to fix this.

My queue will consist of customers who are moved from the waiting room to CustomerQueue. The maximum amount of customers is 33.

Here is my code:

```
package hotelbooking;

public class HotelBooking {
    static int ROOM_CAPACITY = 33;

    private static Customer[] waitingRoom = new Customer[ROOM_CAPACITY]; 
    private static CustomerQueue hotelQueue = new CustomerQueue();
```

This is the method for the user to delete the first customer from the queue.

```
private static void DeleteCustomerFromHotelQueue(Customer[] waitingRoom) {
        System.out.println(hotelQueue.remove() + " ");
    }
```

```
package hotelbooking;

public class CustomerQueue {
    private Customer[] queArray = new Customer[HotelBooking.ROOM_CAPACITY];
    private int front = 0;
    private int end = 0;


    public Customer remove() {
        //if the queArray is not empty
        //remove customer
        Customer removedCustomer = queArray[front];
        //inform that not customer (return null)
        queArray[front] = null;
        front = (front + 1) % queArray.length;
        return removedCustomer;
    }
```

Can someone please help me as I am struggling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use,

```
System.out.println(queArray[(i)%queArray.length] + "");
```

you are starting from the front of the array, so I think you don't need to add that value to it again.

=============Edit=================

I tried a sample and the following worked for me

```
    public void display() {
        //list elements from front to end in the queArray
        for (int i = front; i <= currentSize; i++) {
            System.out.println(queArray[(i)%queArray.length] + "");
            //queArray[i].display();
        }
    }
```

I got the following answer with the code above.

```
City [city=asd]
City [city=zxc]
City [city=zaq]
```

When I changed `i=front` to `i=0` in the for loop, I got the below output.

```
null
City [city=asd]
City [city=zxc]
City [city=zaq]
```

I don't think I can explain it any better. Hope this helps you understand the problem and the solution

Comment: even if I do that it still deletes two customers rather than just one @Nithin

Comment: can you confirm If you have debugged and verified that there are only two in the queue?
if not please confirm, because seeing the code I thnk its pretty alright

Comment: The thing is I am quite new to java, so I do not actually know how the debugger works, but I did try to debug it and the only thing displayed in the debugger is "Listening on 60503
User program running" @Nithin

Comment: If you are using an IDE its very easy, I prefer and use intellij IDEA are you using any?

Comment: I am using netBeans @Nithin

Comment: just click on the line number you want to stop the application and start the application on debug mode.

Comment: it gives me null for the deleted customer @Nithin

Comment: I added 4 and removed 1 and got the output as ```City [city=asd]
City [city=zxc]
City [city=zaq] ```

Comment: I have tried your same example, and have inserted a picture of the outcome above within my question in the Edited section.. @Nithin

Comment: you are iterating from 0, that is wrong I guess. you have to iterate from the `front` of the queue

Comment: I tried in both ways but I keep getting ```null``` @Nithin

Comment: What do you mean both ways, You can try the display method I added in my answer.
It worked for me. you can also delete your target folder and run to make sure there are no build issues.

Comment: I meant that I tried with to use your display method with  ```i = front``` and ```i = 0``` but I keep getting null and I do not understand the "target folder"...  Could you just double check the method that I have for delete() as I have two return statements? Am i getting null because of that? or is it fine?@Nithin

Comment: The null value is coming because you deleted that value from the array and you can see other three values because that is not deleted from the array as `expected`.
Now the only part pending is to modify the `display` method to print only the active part of the array which is what I did in my answer.

Comment: I have implemented your ```display``` method in my program, however I keep getting null for the deleted value from the array and I do not want to have the ```null``` when the queue is displayed.. @Nithin

Comment: I have made one more edit to show the results I received when I set the values,
Its late for me. Hope you will be able to understand it and figure out what you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = front; i < currentSize; i++)
```

You want to start with `i = 0` here

Comment: When you remove one customer, front becomes 1, then you start from 1

Comment: I don't understand, so how am I suppose to implement the code, if it is already implemented in my display () method @sparik

Comment: Change `i = front` to `i = 0` in the for loop

Comment: I did it is giving me null and then the second passenger... @sparik